# Выборка с сортивкой четных дат Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица с датами рождения и с именами людей. Хочу выбрать людей с четными месяцами или днями рождения. К примеру

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE date_of_birth % 2 = 0;
```

не могу написать правильный синтаксис.

Comment: ну так и выбирайте. посмотрите функции postgresql которые дают нужный компонент от даты и применяйте к нему остаток от деления https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/10/functions-datetime

Comment: Нашёл нужный компонент но не могу написать синтаксис

Comment: что, `extract(month from date_of_birth) % 2 = 0` не работает ?

Comment: нет не работает

Comment: "Не работает" это как выражено ?

Comment: По моему отлично работает http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4c2fb/3

Comment: Да вы правы, оказывается надо было дописать extract(month from date_of_birth)::int  % 2 = 0 Спасибо!

Comment: Сразу бы сообщение об ошибке написали, вместо "не работает" гораздо быстрее бы все решилось. не пришлось бы тратить кучу времени на тормознутом sqlfiddle, что бы создать контрольный пример

Comment: Спасибо что уделили время, просто юный и неопытен )

Answer (score -1):

`SELECT * FROM list WHERE extract(month from date_of_birth)::int % 2 = 0;`